# Angular2 RC5 - Form submitting twice

Tags: angular

I've already searched for similar thread and checked their solutions, but they haven't fixed my problem.

I have a form as follows:

```html
  <form *ngIf="_formActive" (ngSubmit)="markAsResolved()" [formGroup]="form">

 ...Form bits and bobs go here

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">
        <button type="submit" class="app-button"
        [disabled]="!form.valid" style="width:100%;">
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

The component in question is importing the following:

```ts
import {FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators} from '@angular/forms'
```

And since I'm on RC5, my `app.module.ts` is loading the following:

```ts
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms} from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule], 
declarations: [ ... ], 
bootstrap: [ AppComponent ], 
providers: [disableDeprecatedForms(), provideForms() 
]})
```

Adding `disableDeprecatedForms()`, `provideForms()` has fixed this for others, but not in my case. Does anyone have any ideas where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to the final release and making sure all deprecated instances have been removed seems to have fixed this.